# Dictionary not loading and spell checking words correctly

Tags: c

I am working on a pset, where we have to implement load, hash, size, check and unload functions  as efficiently as possible using a hash table in such a way that TIME IN load, TIME IN check, TIME IN size, and TIME IN unload are all minimized.
When I test it with a given text, I am having the following message:
WORDS MISSPELLED:     17187
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  1
WORDS IN TEXT:        17756
TIME IN load:         0.00
TIME IN check:        0.01
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.00
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.01
The dictionary is not working correctly as I did not implement hash and check as per conditions but I do not know how. Check must be case insensitive and will only be passed words that contain (uppercase or lowercase) alphabetical characters and possibly apostrophes.
Can you help me on this and point any other potential errors I made.

```
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 17576; // for the first 3 letters so 26*26*26

// Hash table
node *table[N];

unsigned int hash_value; // initialise positive int value
unsigned int word_counter; // initialise positive int word counter

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    //Hash the word to obtain the hash value;
    hash_value = hash(word);
    //Access linked list at the given index in the hash table, we are creating a trav pointer to the head of list indexed via the hash function
     for (node *cursor = table[hash_value]; cursor!= NULL; cursor = cursor->next)
     {
       if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
        {
    return true;
        }
     }
   return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
// hash function was taken from : stackexchange.com
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{

    for (hash_value = 0; *word != '\0'; word++)
    {
    hash_value = *word + 31 * hash_value;
    }

    return hash_value % N;
}


// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    // TODO
    //allocate memory for all node buckets
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }

    //Open dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
if (file == NULL) // check if file is not empty)
    {
        printf("Error, empty file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        //create a new node
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_node == NULL) // check if enough memory
        {
return false;
        }
        else
        {
        strcpy(new_node->word, word); //copies word into new_node->word;
        hash_value= hash(word);
        //Insert the node into the hash table
        new_node->next = table[hash_value];
        /set the head to the new pointer, so it is inserted in front
        table[hash_value] = new_node;
        word_counter ++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        }
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    if (word_counter > 0)
    {
       return word_counter;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // loop through all buckets ( ie all indexes of the array of linked lists)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i]; // place cursor to each bucket
        while (cursor!= NULL) //
        {

            node *tmp = cursor->next; // create a tmp equal to cursor
            free(cursor);
            cursor = tmp;

        }
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: *I did not implement hash and check as per conditions but I do not know how*. Can you please be more specific? Which condition do you specifically have problem with? There is already code in the `hash` and `check` functions. So which exact step or logic do you have problems with?

Comment: Thanks. Check must be case insensitive and will only be passed words that contain (uppercase or lowercase) alphabetical characters and possibly apostrophes. This is not rectified in my code. I think that I have to add toupper or tolower in the hash code as well, to avoid the difference in ascii standards for lower and upper cases.

Comment: *I think that I have to add toupper or tolower in the hash code as well*. Sounds like a reasonable thing to try. So have you attempted to do that?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve the desired result. So was just trying to encourage you to try something. Tip: What if you just ensured the strings stored in the table are always upper or always lower case?

Comment: Thank you, kaylum. I have been trying different options for the last couple of days. Lastly, I edited the hash function like so: hash_value = tolower(*word) + 31 * hash_value; . It compiles but I am still having the same error when running checks.

Comment: I fixed it. It was a mistake in my load function. Which was logical given the fact, it was loading only one word :)